# Installing pushSharp on Xamarin with Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

I have problem with installing PushSharp on Xamarin(Android project mobile app) on Visual Studio 2015 Community.
Error:
Could not install package 'PushSharp 2.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Any solution ?

Best regards,
Lucas

Answer (score 1):

PushSharp is a server side library. You don't include it in your client side (Xamarin Android) project.

As for the error itself, it's essentially saying there are parts of PushSharp that are not compatible with MonoAndroid, so it can not be added to your project. But again, you wouldn't include PushSharp in your client side solutions anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought. After download some samples from github I came to this conclusion.